# Left and right eigenvectors in Julia

Tags: julia, linear-algebra

I have a general real matrix (i.e. not symmetric or Hermitian, etc.), and I would like to find its right eigenvectors and corresponding left eigenvectors in Julia.

Julia's `eigen` function returns the right eigenvectors only. I can find the left eigenvectors by doing

`eigen(copy(M'))`

but this requires copying the whole matrix and performing the eigendecomposition again, and there is no guarantee that the eigenvectors will be in the same order. (The `copy` is necessary because there is no `eigen` method for matrices of type `Adjoint`.)

In Python we have `scipy.linalg.eigs`, which can compute the left and right eigenvectors simultaneously in a single pass, which is more efficient and guarantees that they will be in the same order. Is there something similar in Julia?

Comment: You have access to LAPACK function via `LinearAlgebra.LAPACK` module. Here https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/LinearAlgebra/#LAPACK-Functions-1 is a documentation.

Answer (score 4):

The left eigenvectors can be computed by taking the inverse of the matrix formed by the right eigenvectors:

```
using LinearAlgebra   
A = [1 0.1; 0.1 1]
F = eigen(A)
Q = eigvecs(F) # right eigenvectors 
QL = inv(eigvecs(F)) # left eigenvectors 
Λ = Diagonal(eigvals(F))
# check the results
A * Q ≈ Q * Λ # returns true
QL * A ≈  Λ * QL # returns true, too
# in general we have:
A ≈ Q * Λ * inv(Q)
```

In the above example `QL` are the left eigenvectors.

If the left eigenvectors are applied to a vector is it preferable to compute `Q \ v`, instead of `inv(QL)*v`.

Comment: Is this likely to be a sensible method to calculate them numerically, if my matrices are large and not well conditioned? If so it seems like a great solution.

Comment: In the case, it is indeed better to use the \ operator. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I use the SVD factorization which decomposes a matrix into 3 matrixes USV' = M. The U matrix contains columnwise the left eigenvectors, V the right eigenvectors, and S is diagonal with the sqrt of the eigenvalues.

Note that U = inv(V) if and only if A is symetric (as in PCA where both are used indistinctly on a correlation matrix) and must be positive definite.

Here are some sources where I confirmed my info:
https://www.cc.gatech.edu/~dellaert/pubs/svd-note.pdf
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition

Comment: Thanks, but I should point out that in my question I specified that the matrices I was using weren't symmetric. In that case the SVD is not the same as the eigendecomposition. For them to be equal you need both conditions, that the matrix is symmetric, and that it is positive semi-definite. (Why? Because U and V in the SVD are always orthogonal matrices, and symmetry is the condition for a real matrix to have orthogonal eigenvectors.) So this wouldn't have helped me at that time.